# String validation with multiple levels required using CMD command

Tags: validation, batch-file

I have three requirements I need to meet when validating a password.  I have figure out with the help of others how to verify that the password is at least seven characters long and the user name is not part of the password.

My last requirement is to check to see if a string contains characters from three of the following four groups:

1. English uppercase characters (A through Z)
2. English lowercase characters (a through z)
3. Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
4. Non-alphabetic characters (for example, !, $, #, %)

For example (Hou$e or House1) would pass but (House, house or hou$e) would fail

The call to ":checkRequirement3" is where I would like to make this finial check.  The password is valid if all three requirements are meet.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set /p userName=Username:
set /p userPassword=Password:
call :strlen result userPassword
call :checkRequirement1
call :checkRequirement2
call :checkRequirement3

ECHO Finished
Pause
:strlen <resultVar> <stringVar>
REM THIS DETERMINES THE LENGTH OF THE PASSWORD
(   
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "s=!%~2!#"
    set "len=0"
    for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
        if "!s:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
            set /a "len+=%%P"
            set "s=!s:~%%P!"
        )
    )
)

( 
    endlocal
    set "%~1=%len%"
    exit /b
)

:checkRequirement1
REM THIS CHECKS IF PASSWORD IS AT LEAST 7 CHARACTERS LONG
(
    if %result% GEQ 7 (
    exit /b
    )else (
    GOTO passwordFail
    )

:checkRequirement2
REM THIS CHECKS IF THE USER NAME IS INCLUDED IN THE PASSWORD
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set replacedUsername=!userPassword:%userName%=!
if not !replacedUsername!==%userPassword% (
GOTO passwordFail
)else (
exit /b
)

:checkRequirement3
REM THIS CHECKS IF THE PASSWORD CONTAINS CHARACTERS FROM 3 OF THE FOLLOWING GROUPS
REM English uppercase characters (A through Z)
REM English lowercase characters (a through z)
REM Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
REM Non-alphabetic characters (for example, !, $, #, %)

ECHO This Requirement not finished
Pause
exit /b


:passwordFail
ECHO Password Failed Requirement
PAUSE
exit /b
)
```

Comment: What version of MS-DOS are you using?

Comment: Please clarify, you have used the MS-DOS tag and stated you are using a "DOS batch program" can you tell us what the program is called and if you really are using MS-DOS _(an operating system for which support was stopped more than fifteen years ago)_. Additionally, you need to post your code, _this isn't an ask and you shall receive site_.

Comment: And you were also told in all of your previous batch file questions that MS-DOS is not the same as the CMD prompt in current versions of Windows.

Comment: I am going to assume that you are using this to set the users actual Windows or Domain password.  Why don't you just enforce it with group policy **Password must meet complexity requirements**.

Comment: When you last posted this question, you included more details than you have this time and your question was closed. The idea was supposed to be that you learn something and then update your question not learn nothing and make it even more vague.

Comment: This will be a dos batch file running on Windows 7 or Windows 10.  I apologize ff the MS-Dos tag was not correct.

Comment: It is not a `DOS` batch file.  DOS is dead when the NT kernel came out.  The cmd prompt is not DOS.

Comment: I am still waiting for you to answering my question about why you are not enforcing this with Group Policy.  You are basically trying to emulate exactly what Group Policy can already do.  Why bother having a batch file do this when people can just circumvent the batch file and still set the password however they want.

Comment: I see no point in the extra sets of parentheses you are using in your code.  What is the point of that?

Comment: You need to have spaces before and after the else: `) else (`

Comment: I have the same question. If this is for Active Directory, this exercise is pointless since the system will already tell you if a password does not meet complexity requirements when you try to change it.

Comment: Once again: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/) So please use the tag [tag:ms-dos] *only* when you have really got an MS-DOS-related question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will correctly verify that the password is using 3 out of the 4 groups.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET /P userPassword=UserPassword:
SET /P userPassword=UserPassword=%userPassword:&=^&%
SET /a count=0
echo %userPassword:&=^&% | findstr /R /C:"[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]">null&if not errorlevel 1 SET /a count+=1
echo %userPassword:&=^&% | findstr /R /C:"[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]">null&if not errorlevel 1 SET /a count+=1
echo %userPassword:&=^&% | findstr /R /C:"[!@#&$%%^]">null&if not errorlevel 1 SET /a count+=1
echo %userPassword:&=^&% | findstr /R /C:"[0123456789]">null&if not errorlevel 1 SET /a count+=1

    If %count% GEQ 3 (
        echo Password Meets requirement
        exit /b
    ) else (
        goto passwordFail
    )
```

Comment: What happens when it is 4?  Nul is used with one L.  You can shorten the syntax to: `echo %userPassword% |findstr /R /C:"[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]" >nul &&set /a count+=1`

Comment: Will fail with this password: **Bigtoe&**

Comment: Thanks for wanting to supply a working solution. I've rolled back the answer that overwrote the original question, so that future readers can still read it in a Q&A format. If there was additional material in the edited question that you'd like to copy here, the old version of the question is in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43120516/revisions).

Comment: Thanks halfer, I updated the if statement from EQU to GEQ

Comment: Thanks Sqyashman, I replaced "[!@#&$%%^]" with "[^0-9]".  This checks for all non numeric numbers.

Comment: hmm - isn't `a` or `A` also non numeric? I'd say `Hi` gives you `count` = 3, so `Hi` is a valid password?

Comment: Stephan, thank you for pointing that out.  I will have to put back the original test for "[!@#&$%%^]".  I also discovered that the non alpha check did not solve my problem with &.  I have not been able to figure this out as of yet.  I need a way to replace & with ^& when the user uses & in their password.

Comment: I discovered that I can use %userPassword:&=^&% to escape the ampersand character correctly if the user uses this in their password.  I have updated the code above to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

FOR %%t IN (Hou$e House1 House, house hou$e hou%%%%se hou^^se) DO CALL :test "%%t"

GOTO :EOF

:test
SET /a count=0
>"q43120516.txt" ECHO %~1
TYPE "q43120516.txt"
FOR %%s IN ("[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]"
            "[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]"
        "[!@#&$%%^]"
        "[0123456789]") DO FINDSTR /r %%s "q43120516.txt">nul&IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET /a count+=1
ECHO found %count% groups IN %~1 
DEL "q43120516.txt"
GOTO :EOF
```

naturally, the name of the temporary file "q43120516.txt" is irrelevant.

A few little things to note here:

Certain characters, like `%` and `^` which have a special meaning to `cmd` need to be doubled - sometimes quadrupled.

Yes, I'm aware that in theory you could use `echo %~1|`. Try it.

Yes, I'm aware that in theory you could use `[A-Z]`. Try it.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without creating a txt file?

Comment: @joey.coyle, did you read Magoo's comments. **Yes, I'm aware that in theory you could use echo %~1|. Try it.**

Comment: Squashman, From another post I found it mentioned there is a bug when specifying multiple literal search strings.  I was not able to get your example to work but looking at your example and a couple other post I was able to figure out another way.  I have posted my answer below.

Comment: @joey.coyle, learn to tag people correctly.  I never said to specify multiple literal search strings.